# Windows Server instance VM created from Snapshot fails to Boot on GCE

Tags: windows, google-compute-engine

I am trying to create a new VM instance on Google Compute Engine - GCE from a Snapshot which I created from Windows Server 2012 VM Instance couple of days ago . but I am never able to do RDP cause  may be Windows is not booting up properly.

I get the Serial Port Output as following:

> SeaBIOS (version 1.8.2-20181112_143635-google) Total RAM Size =
>   0x00000001e0000000 = 7680 MiB CPUs found: 2     Max CPUs supported: 2
>   found virtio-scsi at 0:3 virtio-scsi vendor='Google'
>   product='PersistentDisk' rev='1' type=0 removable=0 virtio-scsi
>   blksize=512 sectors=104857600 = 51200 MiB drive 0x000f2a70: PCHS=0/0/0
>   translation=lba LCHS=1024/255/63 s=104857600 Booting from Hard Disk
>   0... 2018/12/27 13:20:39 GCEWindowsAgent: GCE Agent Started (version 4.5.4@1) 2018/12/27 13:21:10 GCEMetadataScripts: Starting startup scripts (version 4.2.1@1). 2018/12/27 13:21:10 GCEMetadataScripts: No
>   startup scripts to run. 2018/12/27 13:21:10 GCEMetadataScripts:
>   Finished running startup scripts

When i read the serial port 2 i get the following:

> Computer is booting, SAC started and initialized.    Use the "ch -?"
>   command for information about using channels.  Use the "?" command for
>   general help. 
>       SAC>  EVENT: The CMD command is now available.  SAC>

So, the firewall rule for tcp:3389 connection is allowed and i created other VM from snapshot successful.

I followed the steps from [stackoverflow forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43682765/windows-server-2012-vm-created-from-snapshot-fails-to-boot-on-gce) and the [Google Cloud troubleshooting](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-instances) but i still cannot access to this VM.

Any other suggestions to fix windows boot problems on GCE?

Answer (score 2):

From the Serial Port Output you have provided it seems that the GCE Windows Agent started and searched for [Startup Script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) and it doesn't find any. So your VM instance is booting up.

You can follow this document to [trobleshoot RDP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-rdp#top_of_page). As mentioned in this document, “If the environment and configurations for the instance are correct, the operating system on the instance might be misconfigured”, so you can follow this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-rdp#windows_password) to check the OS configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The source VM instance of snapshot had a ip internal in windows. I reserved the ip internal from GCP console and i created a new VM instance from snapshot successfully.